# ansible jenkins_plugins mdule : error when playing again a playbook : Jenkins Home not found

Tags: docker, jenkins, ansible

I have a problem with the jenkins_plugins module.
Within a playbook that pull a jenkins docker image (jenkins/jenkins:lts-alpine) and runs it to install the instance and configure it,  I have a task that installs a list of plugins on an instance, which is :

```
- name: Install plugins
  jenkins_plugin:
    owner: "{{ jenkins_process_user }}"
    group: "{{ jenkins_process_group }}"
    name: "{{ item }}"
    state: latest
    timeout: 120
    url: "http://{{ jenkins_hostname }}:{{ jenkins_http_port }}{{ jenkins_url_prefix }}"
    url_username: "{{ jenkins_admin_name }}"
    url_password: "{{ jenkins_admin_password }}"
    with_dependencies: yes
  loop: "{{ jenkinsPlugins }}"
  register: pluginResult
  until: not pluginResult.failed
  retries: 5
  notify: restart_image
  become: True
  become_user: "{{ jenkins_process_user }}"
```

It works correctly when the playbook is run for the first time.
All plugins are installed, and possibly retried in case of problem.

But, when I relaunch exactly the same playbook, Each and every plugin installation is retried up to the max nbr of retry and fails with (for example):

```
failed: [devEnv] (item=blueocean) => {"ansible_loop_var": "item", "attempts": 5, "changed": false, "item": "blueocean", "msg": "Jenkins home directory doesn't exist."}
```

For sure, I have verified that the jenkins home directory actually exists and has the awaited "{{ jenkins_process_user }}" and
"{{ jenkins_process_group }}" owner and group, which is jenkins:jenkins.

Note that the docker container is bound to a local directory which belongs to jenkins:jenkins. To be sure uid and gid are the same on the local machine (a VM created with vagrant) and on the container, the uid:gid are forced to 1001:1001 when starting the container.
I also have checked that it actually the case.

I really cannot explain why I get this error, which clearly makes this playbook not idempotent !

I know that there is a way to install plugins via a shell script provided by Jenkins, but I'd like to stick with ansible playbook as far as possible.

For sure, I can give the whole playbook if you need additional information.

Thanks for your help.
J-L

Comment: Note that looking at the jenkins logs, I see no message concerning the plugin installation. So, it looks like if the error is not related to jenkins itslef, but at ansible / jenkins_plugins level.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I understand the problem.
Reading again the [jenkins_plugins](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/jenkins_plugin_module.html?highlight=jenkins_plugins) documentation, and looking at the jenkins_plugins module code, I found that installation and check already installed plugin version do not run the same code (two different alternatives of a test).
And the second one needs `**JENKINS_HOME**` to be defined, which is optional (defaults to `/var/lib/jenkins`) on the module parameters. I did not set it.
Well, it is actually `/var/lib/jenkins` on the container, but not on the docker controler machine, which is the ansible playbook target where it is `/home/jenkins/jenkins_home`.

So... This question is closed, unless someone has an additional information to give. You're welcome !

Best Regards.